# Show that if $Y \sim X + \delta(X)$, then $G(\cdot)= F(\cdot-\Delta)$ implies $\delta(x) \equiv \Delta$

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Problem is from Bickel - Mathematical Statistics, which I am working through on my own.

Suppose that $Y \sim X + \delta(X)$ where $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\delta$ is continuous. Suppose also that $\delta(x)+x$ is strictly increasing and that the cdfs of $Y$ and $X$, respectively $G$ and $F$, satisfy $G(\cdot)= F(\cdot-\Delta)$ where $\Delta$ is a constant. Show that $\delta(x) \equiv \Delta$.

By our first assumption we have $\mathbb{P}(Y \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(X \leq y-\delta(X))$. On the other hand we have $\mathbb{P}(Y\leq y)=\mathbb{P}(X \leq y -\Delta)$.
Can we write $F(y-\Delta)=F(y-\delta(X))$ and the result may follow by taking the inverse of $F$? But I wish to be explicit about where we used the assumptions on $\delta$.

Comment: The meanings of your symbols are obscure because you employ them in contradictory senses.  Throughout the first paragraph one would suppose $X$ is a random variable and $\delta$ is a function.  Also, because you state $F$ is a cdf and $\Delta$ is a constant, one would presume $y$ is a number and so it follows that $y - \Delta$ must be a *number* and consequently $F(y-\Delta)$ must be a probability. But then $F(y - \delta(X))$ has to be a *random variable* (because it a function of the random variable $X$).  Could you please clarify?

Comment: I've clarified the steps in the second paragraph. Yes, $X,Y$ are r.v.s with cdfs $F, G$. $\delta$ is a function. The goal is to show that it is a constant function and hence $\delta(X)$ is a constant r.v. Indeed then so is $F(y-\delta(X))$.

Comment: That's helpful (+1). But the underlying purpose of my comment was to help you see how problematic your assertion is: "$F(y-\Delta)=F(y-\delta(X))$" doesn't really make sense *until* you know $\delta$ is a constant.  One thought: the assumptions imply $X+\delta(X)$ has a Normal distribution.  When $\delta$ is non-constant, how does the variance of $Y$ compare to that of $X$?